# Invalid literal for int() but converting to float wont work either

Tags: tweepy, valueerror

I'm creating a tweeter bot but the code won't run because of a conversion to an int literal.
Even trying to convert to float creates an error.
What's the solution here?

This is the program code

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import tweepy

appkey= "##############"
appSecret= "##############"
accessToken= "##############"
acessSecret="##############"


latest_tweet_number =0
with open(r'C:\\Users\Kweronda\Desktop\tweek\Quotes.csv') as f: 
    latest_tweet_number = int(f.read())

print(latest_tweet_number)

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Kweronda\Desktop\tweek\Quotes.csv', sep =';')

def tweet_post(msg):
    msg = msg[0:270]
    try:
        auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(appkey, appSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, acessSecret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        try:
            api.verify_credentials()
            print('Authentication Ok')
        except:
            print('Error authenticating')

        api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
        api.update_status(msg)
        print('tweet sent')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for idx, rows in df.iterrows():
    if idx <= latest_tweet_number:
        continue

    hashtags = "#inspiration #motivation quotes"
    tweet_post(rows['Quote']+ ' - '+rows['AUTHOR']+ '\n\n\n' +hashtags)

    with open('C:\\Users\Kweronda\Desktop\tweek\latest.txt', "w") as f:
        f.write(str(idx))

    print('done')
    time.sleep(1800)
```

This is the error;

latest_tweet_number = int(f.read())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'QUOTE;AUTHOR;GENRE\nAge is an issue of mind over matter. If you don't mind, it doesn't matter.;Mark Twain;age\nAnyone who stops learning is old, whether at twenty or eighty. Anyone who keeps learni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` method returns the content of the whole file and I guess that your `Quotes.csv` file is full of quotes, so what are you expecting by trying to cast it to an integer?

At first sight, I think that you don't need that `latest_tweet_number` at all.

And as a side note, you should probably use f-strings to improve readabilty.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mickael. Everyone was ignoring this question but you took the time to look through and offer help. My program is now running fine.

Comment: The mistake I was making is that I was trying to read the wrong file. It's the latest.txt file which I should have been reading as it contains an integer number of the latest tweet. Instead, I was reading the quote.csv file which contains quotes (strings) that cant be converted to integers. Thanks Mickael for making me see that.